# Que al solicitar una foto busque en una carpeta especial

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo este formulario, que sirve para pedir una foto:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><h1>Subir nueva imagen</h1></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="subir_foto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Foto</label>

                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('foto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="foto" value="{{ old('foto') }}" />

                                    @if ($errors->has('foto'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="categoria_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Categoría de la foto</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                     <select name="categoria_id" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach($categorias as $categoria) 
                                            <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}" {{old('categoria_id')==$categoria->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$categoria->nombre}}</option> 
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" placeholder="Explica donde la sacaste o en que consiste" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="fecha" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha en la que se tomó la foto</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="fecha" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fecha') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fecha" value="{{ old('fecha') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('fecha'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Subir Foto
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En si este formulario esta bien, pero quisiera añadirle una mejora.
Al pulsar en el botón `Examinar...`, me lleva a la carpeta "Imagenes":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a donde yo quiero que lleve es a una carpeta dentro del código, llamada public/archivo, donde ya tendre algunas imagenes preparadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo logro que al pulsar el botón se abra la ventana de elegir foto en el lugar que yo deseo?

Comment: Eso es parte del `frontend`, deberías añadir también la etiqueta de javascript y/o jquery, si es tu caso. Si usas algún plugin para la subida indícalo.

Comment: Te diria que no se puede, por razones de seguridad y por razones del sistema operativo

Comment: eso es SO no se puede cambiar!

Comment: @Fly ¿frontend? ¿Como sería eso?

Comment: Has etiquetado la pregunta con `Laravel-5` y el diálogo de subir fichero no está relacionado con Laravel, sería tema de javascript o de la libreria de se use para gestionar la subida. Pero ya ves que comenta que no se puede cambiar.